# how to manage a counter on different blades in laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

Hello i am working on a project i need to send item in session and add limit only 4 item will be add on session. it's working on one blade but when i move to another blade it will show nothing on the button like how many items in the session and when am trying to add another item it will add.

this is  my  script

```
var increment = 0;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".compare").click(function(){
        increment++;
        document.getElementById('compare').innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById('compare').innerHTML = "Compare (" +increment+")";
                if(increment == 4)
                {
                    var array =  document.getElementsByClassName('compare');
                    for (var i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++)
                    {
                        array[i].setAttribute('disabled','');
                    }
                }
```

i am wanted to add only 4  items in the session from every where.
please send any solution .

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var increment = 1;
$(document).ready(function(){
  if(localStorage.getItem("compare") > 0){
    increment = localStorage.getItem("compare");
    document.getElementById('compare').innerHTML = "Compare (" +increment+")";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('compare').innerHTML = "";
  }
  $(".compare").click(function(){
    if(increment == 4)
    {
      var array =  document.getElementsByClassName('compare');
      for (var i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++)
      {
          array[i].setAttribute('disabled','');
      }
    } else {
      increment++;
      localStorage.setItem("compare", increment);
      document.getElementById('compare').innerHTML = "Compare (" +increment+")";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: it's not working properly it's adding more then 4 items and when i remove all items from blade it's showing that 4 items still in blade.

Comment: Please make var increment = 1; initially if you have am item open initially, and when you are removing add this code there increment = increment--; localStorage.setItem("compare", increment);

Comment: Did you find my response useful ?

Comment: it shows 4 item in the blade while there is nothing in the blade

Comment: Can you please provide the whole script from blades ?

Comment: script is too long to send

Comment: You can send html part and script part in 2 separate messages.